# Javascript function for playing a flash file in a certain position

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a button and when it is clicked I'd like to play a flash file in a certain position in my page, using id attribute. I'm using the onClick event in my button. This function doesn't work, is there any solutions?

```
function show(){
document.getElementById("animation").innerHTML = <embed src="flash-file.swf">
}
```

My button is something like this:

```
<button onClick="show()">Show animation</button>
```

Here is where I want to play the flash file in:

```
<div class="span2"> 
<p id="animation"></p>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: There are no quotes around your innerHTML. Typo?

innerHTML = "<embed src='flash-file.swf'>";

you also should really use a ; after every line of code (not including the brackets).

Comment: Yes that's true, but in the main file it is correct. I typed it here again!

Comment: Does the function simply do nothing, or does it start the game over, or does it otherwise not work as expected? What happens?

Comment: @tomysshadow Let me explain a little more. There are 6 buttons and when you click each of them, a description is shown is a certain position and a flash file should be played in another position. The code in the show() function above is placed inside of only one button function. When this code is commented, clicking one button will show the required description in the right position. But when it is not commented, nothing is displayed at all, I mean all buttons seem to be out of order! So not only this function does nothing, but it also makes other functions stop working

Comment: The problem is, this code looks correct, so in order for us to fix your problem, we need to see more of your page. Because from this sample only, I can't see any problems. It looks like it functions how it should function

Answer (score 1):

You can try swfobject, which is a javascript library for embedding flash

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/dynamic-publishing/

Comment: I read about this library but still could not solve my problem. To me who is new in javascript understanding and using this library is quite harder and takes much longer than solving my own problem! Any other solutions? Or if not can you help me write the function if you think it's the only way?